# How can I get outlook to display a background image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, outlook

I'm trying to get outlook to display a background-image. Is another rule I can use in it's place for outlook 2003-2015 email clients? Be see markup below.

```
<table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="mbl-header" align="center" style="width:600px; height:122px; background-image: url('images/banner2.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:600px 100%; padding-left:35px; padding-right:35px;">
        <p style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-align:left;"><strong>As Assistant U.S. Attorney Seth Wilkinson</strong> said in relation to a recent Lacey Act  case, “The message is  clear, you can’t turn a blind eye, you can’t buy products that you know are stolen, make a huge profit off it and then just say, ‘I didn’t know what I was doing</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook 07/10/13 & Outlook.com do not support `background-image` ([Campaign Monitor - CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)). Instead, you can either substitute sliced images (not recommended) for all email clients or a solid background color where `background-image` isn't supported.

[Bulletproof Background Images](http://backgrounds.cm/) is probably the most reliable source.

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So that fixed that problem but another one arised. If I try to add padding to the <td> tags the width of the table is expanded and shows the background color. Is another method I could use to add padding to my p, h2 tags?