# Why image is showing a gap in outlook?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am a creating an email signature using HTML. I am using the HTML table to build it.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    p {
      padding : 0 0 0 0;
      margin: 0 0 2px 0;
    }
    table {
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="329" height="314">
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height: 0;">
        <img src="CC-email-sig_01.png" alt="" style="padding: 0; margin : 0; border : 0; display : block; width: 100%; ">
      </td>
      <td style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px; text-align: right; padding-right: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
        <p style="color: #3F4B54;">Sean Clough</p>
        <p style="color: #3F4B54;">Writer/Owner </p>
        <p style="color: #25408F;">Clough Copywriting</p>
        <br/>
        <p><span style="color: #25408F;">m</span> <span style="color: #3F4B54;">0419 031 052</span> </p>
        <p><span style="color: #25408F;">a</span> <span style="color: #3F4B54; font-weight: bold;">PO Box 439</span> </p>
        <p style="color: #3F4B54;">Bedford WA 6052</p>
        <p><a href="http://cloughcopywriting.com.au" target="_blank">cloughcopywriting.com.au</a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#25408F">
      <td style="padding-left: 22px;">
        <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color : #fff; margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;">Follow me on</p>
        <a href="#"><img src="CC-email-sig_06.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="CC-email-sig_08.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="CC-email-sig_10.png" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td width="184">
        <img src="CC-email-sig_04.png" alt="" style="padding: 0; margin : 0; border : 0; display : block; width: 100%; ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="vertical-align: baseline;">
      <td colspan="2" style="line-height: 100%;">
        <img src="CC-email-sig_12.png" alt="" width="329" style="padding: 0; margin : 0; border : 0; display : block; width: 100%; ">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now In the browser, it looks like bellow image:

[image]

but in outlook, the image looks like bellow:

[image]

If you see then you can notice the red arrow. Here I am using an image for showing the curve but It's not full width in outlook but perfect on the browser.

Also, padding between Man image and text is not same.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: the rounded corner is an img? I mean the very bottom

Comment: yes, It is @DanielH

Comment: what size is that img, I want to reproduce it first

Comment: Total table size is 329px so that image should be 329px width.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically,because of the outlook limitations, I recommend you to use an entire background image for your last row.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/css60wL2/

```
<tr background="https://s20.postimg.org/cz6xu0nz1/bg_Footer.png">
      <td style="padding-left: 22px;">
        <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color : #fff; margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;">Follow me on</p>
        <a href="#"><img src="CC-email-sig_06.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="CC-email-sig_08.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="CC-email-sig_10.png" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td width="184">
        <img src="CC-email-sig_04.png" alt="" style="padding: 0; margin : 0; border : 0; display : block; width: 100%; ">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Hmm, so, try adding "box-sizing" in this tag....

`<p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color : #fff; margin: 10px 0 10px 5px; box-sizing: border-box">Follow me on</p>`

If this does not work, I advice you to remove the last row and create a new image with border bottom radius to use as your whole footer background.

Comment: No luck with that.

Comment: Try to use my fiddle example. Save the image footer and try.

Comment: I have used your fiddle example and replace background value but it's not showing the background image in outlook.

Comment: Well man, outlook sucks hehehe. I found out this post. Maybe it can help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430160/how-can-i-get-outlook-to-display-a-background-image