# Background image not loading in Outlook and Mail.Ru

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        #switcher {
          display:block;
        background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQY2xFICSLTeJuWDALDsvc7YtIAdsNVpDWtRtOaGgPyCaPoGkjUvg') !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-position: center !important;
        width: 300px !important;
        height: 250px !important; 
    }
  } 
</style>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.emailonacid.com"><span id="switcher"></span></a>
</body>
```

Above which works in Gmail and Yahoo but not in Outlook and Mail.Ru. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get outlook to display a background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430160/how-can-i-get-outlook-to-display-a-background-image)

Comment: This code will never work since Outlook does not support media queries or background images in this manner. You'll have to try VML code like @RasmusGlenvig posted already.

Answer (score 2):

`background` is not supported in Outlook, that's why it's not showing.

What you could do, is using this **[background image tool](https://backgrounds.cm/)** to generate a background image that would be shown in Outlook.

Add the following right after the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<div style="background-color:#7bceeb;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQY2xFICSLTeJuWDALDsvc7YtIAdsNVpDWtRtOaGgPyCaPoGkjUvg" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQY2xFICSLTeJuWDALDsvc7YtIAdsNVpDWtRtOaGgPyCaPoGkjUvg">
```

and this right before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I hope it's helping you to achieve what you wan't.

Comment: OP wants a background image in a span tag i believe, the code/example above would display background for the whole email. Plus1 for the answer.

Comment: It's also possible to select it in a table cell instead of the whole email. Thanks for the upvote. :)

Comment: Yes it is possible. Its The second radio button on the page. I have been using a different variation of the cell background code but since your answer and link covers it I saw no need for a new answer that would repeated things ;-)

Comment: Using above code background image is display but i want to change background image when it opens in mobile for tacking purpose.